# Want to increase disk space for Ubuntu (I have installed is along windows 7)

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning

```
vishal@vishal-ThinkPad-T430:~$ ls -al /dev/sda*
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 8, 0 Jul 24 11:44 /dev/sda
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 8, 1 Jul 24 11:36 /dev/sda1
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 8, 2 Jul 24 11:36 /dev/sda2
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 8, 3 Jul 24 11:36 /dev/sda3
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 8, 4 Jul 24 11:36 /dev/sda4
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 8, 5 Jul 24 11:36 /dev/sda5
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 8, 6 Jul 24 11:36 /dev/sda6
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 8, 7 Jul 24 11:36 /dev/sda7
vishal@vishal-ThinkPad-T430:~$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda6        99G  8.1G   86G   9% /
none            4.0K     0  4.0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
udev            3.8G  4.0K  3.8G   1% /dev
tmpfs           767M  1.3M  766M   1% /run
none            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none            3.8G  156K  3.8G   1% /run/shm
none            100M   32K  100M   1% /run/user
vishal@vishal-ThinkPad-T430:~$
```

Comment: You don't seem to need more space at the moment. And please [edit] your question to clarify what exactly you want. At the moment, it is unclear.

Answer (score 2):

- Important: Before you start messing with partitions make a backup of your personal data. If you mess up you might get it back with something like testdisk but that will take a lot of time and gas mixed result.
- [Create a gParted Live DVD or USB](http://gparted.org/livecd.php) like you would make an Ubuntu installation disk;
- Boot from it.

The 2 steps to do from here:

- Shrink the partition you want to make smaller. Let that task finish before proceeding;
- Add the unallocated space to the partition you want to make larger.

You can only merge with the unallocated space to partitions next to it these 2 task might need to be repeated. If you want to move space from sda1 to sda4 and sda2 and sda3 are in between you need to shrink sda1, add the new free space to sda2, shrink sda2, add to sda3, shrink sda3, add to sda4.

If you want a more specific answer add an image from gParted into the question. The information you provided does not tell us what partitions are used by Windows (sda1 through sda5 could be a Windows system, a data partition or recovery partitions); only the sda6 is your Ubuntu system.